# React native linking mail api support subject, body?

Tags: react-native

Hello I use Linking api to open mailto.

I try to call mail app using below

```
Linking.openURL('mailto://somethingemail@gmail.com&subject=abcdefg&body=body')
```

but It will open maill app with to:somethingemail@gmail.com&subject=abcdefg&body=body

subject and body are empty

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You need to remove the '//' in your url and add a '?' : `mailto:somethingemail@gmail.com?subject=abcdefg&body=body`

Comment: it just fill email adress

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html)

Comment: Works fine on my device. Are you on Android ? Have you changed the url with the '?' as per my example ?

Comment: how to send a link using email?

Comment: how to simply open mail inbox ?

Comment: Tip: If you want to use spaces in your subject or body you need to wrap your message in encodeURIComponent to replace the space to %20 
e.g. `mailto:somethingemail@gmail.com?subject=${encodeURIComponent("This is a subject")}`
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36680#issuecomment-1488093034

Answer (score 4):

Here are my cases:

- SMS link:

`return (Platform.OS === 'android')
      ? sms:1-408-555-1212?body=yourMessage
      : sms:1-408-555-1212&body=yourMessage;`

- Mail link:

`return (Platform.OS === 'android')
      ? mailto:foo@example.com?cc=?subject=yourSubject&body=yourMessage
      : mailto:foo@example.com?cc=&subject=yourSubject&body=yourMessage;`

**Note: your mail url must contain `cc=` even if you don't have any cc emails.**

- iOS: you use `?`
- android: you use `&`

for the first parameter.

Comment: Did you intend to say, iOS use '&' and Android '?' before 'subject='.  
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html

Comment: @EdoftheMountain Before body (SMS) and subject (Mail link). Really sorry for the late reply.