# Trying to add mailto - react native

Tags: react-native, mailto, react-native-ios

Mailto appears to not be working. All that happens is that the icon appears to be pressed, but no action occurs. Shoots out this warning:

## Warning

[image: warning]

## Code

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:mailto@deniseleeyohn.com?subject=abcdefg&body=body')}>
                      <Icon style={styles.icons} size={SIZE} name='envelope'/> 
    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Link not work on Simulator.

[React native linking mail api support subject, body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815517/react-native-linking-mail-api-support-subject-body)

[Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html)

Comment: This is the original tutorial I followed. Strangely, it works on a physical device.

Answer (score 15):

Use this code :-

```
Linking.openURL(`mailto:${props.ArticleData.email}`)
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution wast tested on an android emulator with a GoogleApi system image:

[image]

After you have the emulator configured you can use something like you are using:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Linking.openURL('mailto:mailto@deniseleeyohn.com?subject=abcdefg&body=body')}>
      <Text>email1</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

or

You can use a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autolink

```
       <AutoLink
         text="email2 (mailto:mailto@deniseleeyohn.com)"
       />
```