# Mailto url scheme shows white blank pop in flutter ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, url-scheme, mailto

I am trying to open compose mail page of native default app in ios using flutter app but unable to do it. It shows me blank pop up window.

I have tried all kind of solution related to url_launcher but nothing is working for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L20lb.png)

Below is my code which i am using for opening native app from flutter app.

```
_sendingMails() async {
    const url = 'mailto:xyz@mail.com';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

I have added url scheme as well in info.plist file.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>  
<array>         
  <string>mailto</string>            
</array>
```

But still it gives me white pop up window in ios and in android its working fine.

Comment: Probably, links don't work on iOS simulators
Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098235/trying-to-add-mailto-react-native)

Answer (score 0):

To send mail does not work in the 'simulator'.

Because the simulator does not provide default mail app.

**Try it on a real device.**

It'll work out.