# Is it possible to send email with react-native without node.js?

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to send an email through react-native without node.js or any back-end?
I want to send an email to notify the admin when user registered (on firebase)...

Comment: You mean without user interaction, in the background ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815517/react-native-linking-mail-api-support-subject-body

Comment: I mean that I want to let the admin know when user registered, I'm using firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a server to make the requests to send mail you cannot. You can use a cloud service or function to do this. I'm sure one is available with firebase. If not, I have previously used mailgun: https://www.mailgun.com/